# How do polymorphic associations get their imageable_id value in the New action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still having a very difficult time with polymorphic associations, because I can't do nested forms. However, without even getting into forms, I can't even do what I would think is a very basic task.

For example:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many subscriptions, dependent: :destroy, as: :imageable
end
```

.

```
#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy, as: :imageable
end
```

.

```
#app/models/subscription.rb
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

if I run `Company.first.subscriptions.create(name: "Random")`, this works, but the following fails:

```
@company = Company.new({:name => "Random Company Name"})
@company.subscriptions.build
@company.save
```

Why does this fail? It seems because `@company.subscriptions` shows an associated `Subscription` with `imageable_type: Company` but `imageable_id: nil`. This is a legitimate case where I don't want to add a subscription but I want to add a `Company`.

If that is the case, then how do I get `imageable_id`? With a polymorphic association, shouldn't `imageable_id` get auto filled when @company saves?

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you call

```
@company = Company.new({:name => "Random Company Name"})
```

You initialize a new record without saving it, meaning it has an ID of nil.

When you then call

```
@company.subscriptions.build
```

It doesn't know what company_id to assign the new subscription. Try changing your first line to:

```
@company = Company.create({:name => "Random Company Name"})
```

This will mean @company gets assigned an ID, which can then be assigned to the subscription

Comment: I figured it out. I just had to make subscriptions optional with `belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true, optional: true`.  Would have never thought this.